# how to remove space after colon when writing dict in yaml file

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I need to write a yaml file in a format like:

```
abc:0 "def"
```

my current solution is to make a dict like:

```
{abc:'0 "def"'}
```

but if I use `yaml.dump(dict,file)` to write it, it will become:

`abc: 0 "def"` (there is a space after the colon, before the values.)

how can I remove the space after the colon?

=====================================================================

or the question could be:

if I make a dict like:

```
{abc:'"def"'}
```

then the output will be

```
abc: "def"
```

then how can I add a '0' after the colon?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the YAML spec mandate a space after the colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124227/why-does-the-yaml-spec-mandate-a-space-after-the-colon)

Comment: thanks! I think so. Then I guess I can't output it as I wanted. :(

Answer (score 0):

`abc:0 "def"` is indeed valid YAML. However, it gets loaded as a single scalar containing the string `"abc:0 \"def\""`. The colon is not interpreted as end of an implicit key because it is not followed by a space. Conversely, to produce this YAML, you would need to serialize the string:

```py
import yaml, sys

yaml.dump("abc:0 \"def\"", sys.stdout)
```

This yields

```yaml
abc:0 "def"
...
```

`...` is the document end marker. PyYAML always emits it if you serialize a single scalar. It doesn't change the YAML's meaning.

Now the real question is, is this what you want? A YAML file that is interpreted as single string? If you want this, why would you even use YAML – you could simply write the string to the file.