# How to pass dictionary elements from hydra config file

Tags: python, yaml, fb-hydra

I am trying to instantiate objects with hydra, I have a class [`torchio.transforms.RemapLabels`](https://torchio.readthedocs.io/transforms/preprocessing.html#remaplabels) that I am using in my config file:

```
_target_: torchio.transforms.RemapLabels
```

The problem is that `torchio.transforms.RemapLabels` takes dictionary elements as input, how do I pass those from my hydra config file? (`config.yaml`)?

I am getting error when instantiating:

```
TypeError: Error instantiating 'torchio.transforms.preprocessing.label.remap_labels.RemapLabels' : __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'remapping'
```

example usage of remap label:

```
transform = torchio.RemapLabels({2:1, 4:3, 6:5, 8:7})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options: you can pass the inputs as positional arguments or as named arguments.

#### Using named arguments (a.k.a. keyword arguments) in your `yaml` file:

```yaml
_target_: torchio.transforms.RemapLabels
remapping:
  2: 1
  4: 3
  6: 5
  8: 7
masking_method: "Anterior"
```

or, using json-style maps:

```yaml
_target_: torchio.transforms.RemapLabels
remapping: {2: 1, 4: 3, 6: 5, 8: 7}
masking_method: "Anterior"
```

#### Using positional arguments in your `yaml` file:

```yaml
_target_: torchio.transforms.RemapLabels
_args_:
  - 2: 1
    4: 3
    6: 5
    8: 7
  - "Anterior"
```

Or, equivalently:

```yaml
_target_: torchio.transforms.RemapLabels
_args_:
  - {2: 1, 4: 3, 6: 5, 8: 7}
  - "Anterior"
```

For more information, please refer to the docs on [Instantiating objects with Hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/).

Comment: Note that the space after the comma is mandatory for hydra (i.e. use {key: value} and not {key:value}) .

Comment: I think you mean "colon" (`:`), not "comma" (`,`).
This requirement is due to the [yaml spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124227/why-does-the-yaml-spec-mandate-a-space-after-the-colon).

Comment: Indeed, thks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what Jasha said, if the constructor of the class you're targeting manually checks the type of its arguments (`if isinstance(remapping, dict):`)
then you should instruct Hydra to convert the config data into dicts:

```py
transform = hydra.utils.instantiate(config, _convert_="partial")
```